# Grant Admin rights to an entire registry Hive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, permissions, windows-registry

There is a way via a CLI or GUI application to grant Admin rights to **ALL** the keys/Values of an entire registry **Hive** (like **System**, **SAM**, **ntuser.dat**, etc)?

The problem is that I'm using the `Dism` tool provided by **Microsoft** to service and deploy **Windows**, I'm trying to perform some `Dism` operations that removes pre-installed packages from a **WIM** image that I've previouslly mounted, I'm able to remove few packages but for most of them `Dism` reports me that I have access denied to touch the Hives, so I suppose that to properlly remove some packages **Dism** needs to update or delete keys from the **WIM** Hives, then I need to grant **Admin** rights to those keys!

I normally use `SetACL` application to grant **Admin** rights on a single or multiple keys/values of the local Registry, but for a Hive I don't have idea how to.

PS: I've wasted days trying to investigate and search for information but by the moment I didn't find **ANY** existing information related to how to perform this operation, why?, why there is no (or at least not easy to found) information about this kind of operation over all the **World Wide Web**?, I'm miss understanding the real problem or doing something wrong?.

This is the command that I'm using:

```
.\Dism.exe /Remove-Package /PackageName:"(name)" /Image:"(mounted dir)" /English /LogPath:"(file.log)" /LogLevel:"2"
```

And this is a sample from the log which is full of this kind of Hive Errors:

> 2014-04-12 04:29:18, Error                 CBS    Only package owners
>   can remove package:
>   Checkpoint-VpnPlugin-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~6.3.9600.16384
>   [HRESULT = 0x80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED]
>
> 2014-04-12 04:29:18, Info                  CBS    Failed to unload
>   offline registry:
>   {bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}C:/WinMount/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE,
>   the client may still need it open. [HRESULT = 0x80070005 -
>   E_ACCESSDENIED]
>
> 2014-04-12 04:29:18, Info                  CBS    Failed to unload
>   offline registry:
>   {bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}C:/WinMount/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM,
>   the client may still need it open. [HRESULT = 0x80070005 -
>   E_ACCESSDENIED]
>
> 2014-04-12 04:29:18, Info                  CBS    Failed to unload
>   offline registry:
>   {bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}C:/WinMount/Windows/System32/config/SECURITY,
>   the client may still need it open. [HRESULT = 0x80070005 -
>   E_ACCESSDENIED]
>
> 2014-04-12 04:29:18, Info                  CBS    Failed to unload
>   offline registry:
>   {bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}C:/WinMount/Users/default/ntuser.dat,
>   the client may still need it open. [HRESULT = 0x80070005 -
>   E_ACCESSDENIED]

I'm douing all this in a **VirtualMachine**.

I don't know if it matters but notice that I have granted full **Admin** rights on all the files and folders of the mounted directory, I can copy/write/delete from system-restricted directories, I mean that seems I don't have any problem with the files rights.

Comment: Are you running any anti virus? Turn off all AV programs or maybe you are not running the cmd line as administrator when you execute dism

Comment: @Logman no I don't have any AV installed in the VM (even I disabled Windows Defender), and I'm running the account as Admin, also I log session from the hidden Administrator account which has all rights, thanks for comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do doesn't work out of the box. You get  E_ACCESSDENIED becasue the packages still belong to a Windows Edition. You must kill that dependency first.

There is [already a tool out for a while](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x-registry-tweak/) which does all steps for you.

Run `install_wim_tweak.exe /p <MountPath> /l` to enum all packages. Now run `install_wim_tweak.exe /p <MountPath> /c FEATURE /r` to kill it.

Example:

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /p "C:\Mount" /c Microsoft-Hyper-V /r
```

This kills all Hyper-V related features from the mounted WIM in folder C:\Mount.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I would like to mark your answer as the accepted one but I still having a relative problem, the `wimtweak` tool is not able to remove packages from my WIM (it says that removal success without throwing any error but really are not removed, packages still installed after) but I've solved it just using the command `wimtweak.exe /p <MountPath>` to take rights + mount registry, then to remove packages I use DISM (yes now DISM can remove packages successfully after using that single `wimtweak` command), the problem is, how to cleanup the image after packages are removed?

Comment: I mean that I would like to clean the WinSXS directory after removing all the packages to remove the associated files of removed packages, but if I try the DISM command with the parameters `/CleanUp-Image /StartComponentCleanup` after removing all the packages DISM says me that I can't cleanup 'cause pending packages operations. I'm lost. Please, could you help me?

Comment: this is correct. Removing the packages requires some changes which can be only done when the is Windows running. And running the cleanup command requires that there are no pending changes.